# liipimaginebundle , the cache/media folder is not generated ,

Tags: thumbnails, symfony, symfony-forms, liipimaginebundle

i installed the "liipimaginebundle" and i tried to resize some picture ...the problem is when i apply the twig filter :

### i dont find any folder (/media/cache) in the web folder , nothing is generated :/

> app/config.yml

---

```
liip_imagine :
resolvers :
    default :
        web_path : ~

filter_sets :
    cache : ~
    produit :
        quality : 75
        filters :
            thumbnail  : { size : [120, 90], mode : outbound }
```

> routing.yml

```
gt_it:
    resource: "@GtItBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
utilisateurs:
    resource: "@UtilisateursBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

> composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
       "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "liip/imagine-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "^1.6"





    },
```

[and this the inspect html url element , but ther's no image or folder called media/cache ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Nn9.png)

fo that more i'm using windows so i think i have no prob with the permission ...guys please help me

Comment: try to create the media/cache folder manually dont forget to chown and chmod